# How do I start a group of containers, keep them running, then begin an identical process in each container

Tags: mysql, docker, sftp

As part of an application stress test, I need to start 200 Docker containers, keep all containers alive until the creation process is complete, then issue a command to each container to begin a process that will stress test a server.  Each container must run two processes ... multiple SFTP file transfer and multiple writes to a MySQL database.  This can be achieved by a very long (15 minute) sleep time setting in a shell script to allow all containers to be created, but it would be much better to simply create the containers, and after all are created issue a command to each container to start processing.  In my desired scenario, I can start all the containers, but they stop before I can begin processing and cannot be restarted.

Comment: One other thought ... If I am able to issue and reissue the processing command, it would be helpful.  Simply haven't been able to make the containers stay alive.

Comment: You can think of a container as a process, there's no need to start it if it's not going to do anything. Just start the containers when they actually need to do something.

Comment: The containers will only be inactive during the container creation process.  Once all containers are created, I want to issue a command to each container to begin processing data.  Processing during the container creation process overloads the CPU on the host system.  I need to be able to issue and reissue the processing command to maintain the stress level on the destination system.

Comment: Try rephrasing your question and replace 'container' with 'process'. What does "The PROCESS will only be inactive during the PROCESS creation process" even mean? That will help us answer your question better.

Comment: Let me try to explain this again.  I need to create 200 Docker containers, wait until all containers are created, then send a command that initiates processing to each container.  Processing involves running an application that connects to a MySQL database and writes data to the database, and a process that uses SFTP to transmit image files to a receiving system.  The problem is that the containers stop and will not receive the command to begin processing.

Comment: The command to initiate processing of the containers _IS_ the creation of the containers (`docker run`). Unless you want to setup a server in each container to listen for a signal there's no other way. There's absolutely no need to wait until all 200 containers are created if you're doing things right.

Comment: Just to re-iterate, sending a signal to 200 running containers to do something (incorrect method) should have no advantage over simply starting 200 containers to do that same thing (correct method).